# Ranking differences between google yandex and bing

Tags: google-search, search-results, bing, yandex

I have a 15 year-old website that performed well seo-wise in the past. About 1 month ago, I updated contents, url structure etc and migrated it to a new domain, and notified this to google via the search console (of course after making necerray redirections from the old domain to the new one).

I know this process impacts website's rankings and it takes some time for google to process the migration.

However, I notice that google is almost ignoring all of my important pages, which get very high scores from seo tools for any seo parameters (pagespeed, content quality, text to html ratio, keyword density etc). Even if not ignored, they rank on or after 8th page in serps.

On the other hand, those same pages have started to rank among the first 5 results both on yandex and bing. For the most important and competitive keywords (those describing the actual service being sold) the site is ranked number 1 or 2 on yandex.

I don't know about bing's algorithm, but afaik, yandex's algorithm is very similar to that of google.

So, why is there such a huge difference? Can I assume that google makes things slower and sooner or later, I will get similar rankings on google? Or, should I be worried about something I might be missing about google seo?